# javascript - setTimeout interval decay and recovery

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How would I go about creating a self-adjusting timer? I really suck at math and I need your help.

My baseline is 2 seconds

```
 var minInterval = 2000;
 var maxInterval = 60000;
 var interval = minInterval;

 setTimeout(function findResultsInterval()
 {
    var results = getResults();
    var totalAmt = results.total;
    var newAmt = findNew(results);
    var newRatio = newAmt / totalAmt;

    //magic to adjust timer between minInterval and maxInterval
    //considering the amount of new items with these rules:
    // 100% new items sets the interval = 2000
    // 0% new items - 60000
    interval = ???;

    setTimeout(findResultsInterval, interval);

 }, interval);
```

I would love if it could slow down and speed up instead of going directly from 2 seconds to 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're just calculating a percentage of the maxInterval, like this:

```
interval = (1 - newRatio) * (maxInterval - minInterval) + minInterval;
```